# auto_route redirect with declarative routes

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation

I have an iOS app with auto_route which uses declarative routes as in this example for the root router: https://autoroute.vercel.app/advanced/authentication. I use a custom protocol deep link to redirect to the app from an oAuth authentication.

Problem is now that I cannot use a route guard to intercept the deep link coming in because route guards are not allowed with declarative routing.

The solution that I have found is to use the info in `AppRouter().routeInfoProvider().value.location` in the code that I pass to the `routes` parameter of `AppRouterDelegate.declarative` as in the above mentioned example. Is that a sensible solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use route guards throughout(even for your oAuth flow), because I think using declarative and route guards can make your implementations inconsistent. The declarative example was provided as a simpler and easy-to-understand alternative to using route guards. Thank you.

https://autoroute.vercel.app/advanced/route_guards

Comment: I would prefer to find a workaround for the deep link because I like the simplicity of the declarative routing.